# Is data stored in one location when a variable is assigned the value of another, and the value of the second isn't changed?

Tags: perl

Given this Perl code:

```
sub a{
my $variable = $_[0];
}
```

The content of $variable is the same as that of `$_[0]`. It doesn't change for the life-span of the variable.

Does interpretation of the assignment prevent Perl from creating two memory locations for the contents of `$_[0]`?

Comment: I used the term figuratively, as a place to store data.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what you mean, but there are two "containers". `$_[0]` and the argument passed to the function consist of one. `my $variable` creates another one. Assignment doesn't create containers/scalars/variables.

---

Based on comments, it appears your question is actually about if `my $variable` and/or the assignment are optimized away. They're not.

```
>perl -MO=Concise,-exec,a -e"sub a { my $variable = $_[0]; return; }"
main::a:
1  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v
2  <#> aelemfast[*_] s
3  <0> padsv[$variable:1,2] sRM*/LVINTRO   <-- my $variable
4  <2> sassign vKS/2                       <-- scalar assignment in void context
5  <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:1) v
6  <0> pushmark s
7  <@> return K
8  <1> leavesub[1 ref] K/REFC,1
-e syntax OK
```

(I added `return` since the sub returns `$variable` otherwise.)

`my $variable` is not optimised away, since the assignment can't be optimised away, since it could have side-effects for magical args.

Magical variables have code attached to them. The code is called when you read from them, for example (e.g. getching from `$ENV{PATH}` translates to `getenv`, and storing, `putenv`). I suppose you could evaluate `$_[0]` as the assignment would and then clear the result from the stack, but that's a lot of work to remove code that should never exist.

If you want to find unused lexicals, use [`perlcritic`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlcritic).

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator `=` *always*¹ copies the value. This means that if `$_[0]` contains a very large string, then `$variable` will contain another and completely seperate very large string.

If this bothers you, you could use references:

```
my $reference = \$_[0];
# the value can be accessed as $$reference
```

---

<sub>1. Except when the value on the right hand side of the assignment would be discarded anyway.</sub>

Comment: Will perl not recognize that `$variable` is not needed?

Comment: @Bharath Muralidhar, No, `my $variable` is not optimised away, since the assignment can't be optimised away, since it could have side-effects for magical args.

Comment: a() doesn't change the value of `$_[0]`. What side-effect would be seen if the $variable is removed?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually speaking, a normal assignment always makes a shallow copy of the data.

By "shallow", I mean that when `my $foo = \@array` is a reference to, say, an array, then `my $bar = $foo` makes `$bar` into a different reference to the same array, so when you `push @$bar, $quux`, you're appending to the same array as you would when you `push @$foo, $quux`, but if you do `$bar = \@another_array`, then `$foo` is still pointing to the original array.

By "conceptually speaking", I mean that you can think of it that way. As an optimization, Perl does occasionally keep the two variables in the same part of memory until you attempt to modify one. This is called "copy-on-write". But unless you dig deeper under the hood than most XS code goes, the idea is that you should never notice it happening.

There are however situation where you can have multiple variable referring to the same data. These are generally referred to as "aliases". Within `foreach`, `grep` and `map` blocks, the `$_` variable (or another lexical variable in the case of `foreach`) is an *alias* for the item currently being processed:

```
foreach my $foo ($bar, $baz) {
    # In here, $foo is an alias for $bar, then $baz.
    # When $foo is aliased to $bar, then modifiying $foo
    # also modifies $bar, and vice versa.
}
```

Aliases can also be created by assigning to a glob. Here's an example:

```
our $foo;
my $bar = 19;
*foo = \$bar;        # alias $foo to $bar
$foo++;
$bar++;
print $foo + $bar;   # 42
```

Note that `$foo` there is a package variable (`our`); glob assignment only works for package variables. But Data::Alias and Devel::LexAlias allow you to do similar things with lexical variables (`my`).

The other situation where aliases crop up is the `@_` array in subs. Here:

```
sub quux {
    # In here, $_[0] is an alias for $foo
    # In here, $_[1] is an alias for $bar
}

quux($foo, $bar);
```

Lastly, aliases can also be faked with careful use of tied variables.

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what you mean by two containers. How can a scalar have two items?

Please note: `$_[0]` is an alias to the first argument in the calling function. If the first argument is a variable, and `$_[0]` is change, then the value of the **variable in the calling code** is changed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub a {
  $_[0] = 1;
}

my $var = 0;
a( $var );
print "$var\n";
```